# Aggregate ranges by merging

Tags: postgresql, aggregate, range-types

There aren't any [Aggregate functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-agg.html) for [Range types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rangetypes.html) in PostgreSQL.

How to aggregate ranges using a merge operation?

This solution works but does not look optimal:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE test_ranges (r int4range);
INSERT INTO test_ranges VALUES ('[4, 8)'), ('[12, 45)'), (NULL);

SELECT int4range(min(lower(r)), max(upper(r))) FROM test_ranges;
=> '[4,45)'
```

Comment: What's your actual question? Are you just looking for the smallest possible range containing all the ranges in your selection? Your approach looks correct at first sight, but the answer will depend on the inclusiveness/exclusiveness of both bounds... which I don't think is taken into account if there were [1,2), (1,2), [1, 2], (1, 2]

Comment: The solution given in the question does not handle +/- infinity correctly. Victor's solution does.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Create an aggregate](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createaggregate.html) using the `range_merge(anyrange, anyrange)` function.

```
CREATE AGGREGATE range_merge(anyrange)
(
  sfunc = range_merge,
  stype = anyrange
);

SELECT range_merge(r) FROM test_ranges;
=> '[4,45)'
```

Comment: How would you deal in your `range_merge` function the *inclusiveness* or *exclusiveness* of your bounds?

Comment: @joanolo According to the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-range.html#RANGE-FUNCTIONS-TABLE): _The smallest range which includes both of the given ranges._ I guess _inclusiveness_ or _exclusiveness_ are handled internally by PostgreSQL. Do you have an example that would be problematic?

Comment: You're right. My bad... I didn't read the documentation carefully enough.

Comment: Isn't this *slower* than the simple solution in the question (for a non-trivial number of rows to aggregate)?